# Quick way to solve $yy''-(y')^2=y^4$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a simple yet ugly ODE (arising from Euler-Lagrange equations):
$$yy''-(y')^2=y^4$$

What method could I use to quickly solve it?

I began to notice that by dividing by $y^2$ I can write it as 
$$ (y'/y)'=y^2 $$
which implies that $y'=y^3t+cy$ for some constant $c$. But even there I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: You're correct that $(y'/y)'=y^2$.  But that does not imply that $y'=y^3t+cy$.

Comment: For what it's worth, Wolfram *Mathematica* gives
$$\frac{2 c_1 e^{\sqrt{c_1}(x+c_2)}}{e^{2 \sqrt{c_1} (x+c_2)}-c_1}$$
and
$$\frac{2 c_1 e^{\sqrt{c_1} x+\sqrt{c_1} c_2}}{1 - c_1 e^{2\sqrt{c_1} (c_2+x)}}$$
as solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

introduce a variable $u$ by  $$y' = yu, \quad u = \frac {y'} y \tag 1 .$$ then 
$$u' = \frac{y''} y - \frac{y'^2}{y^2} =\frac{yy''-y'^2}{y^2} = y^2 \tag 2$$  dividing $(1)$ by $(2),$  we have $$\frac{dy}{du} = \frac uy\implies u^2 = y^2 + c , y'^2 = u^2y^2 =y^2(y^2 + c)  $$  that is $$y' = \pm y\sqrt{c+y^2} \to \int\frac{dy}{y\sqrt{c+y^2}} = \pm x + d.$$

Answer (score 3):

You can write:
$$y'' = \frac{dy'}{dx}=\frac{dy'}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=y'\frac{dy'}{dy}=\frac12\frac{dy'^2}{dy}.$$
Now we introduce $p=y'^2$, and rewrite your equation:
$$\frac y2 \frac{dp}{dy}-p=y^4.$$
Solve $$\frac y2 \frac{dp}{dy}-p=0;\quad \frac{dp}{p}=2\frac{dy}{y}\Longrightarrow p=Cy^2.$$

Let's try $p=Cy^n$: $$\frac y2\frac{dp}{dy}-p=\frac12 Cny^n - Cy^n=y^4,$$
and $n=4$, $C=1$. So we have general solution $p=y^4 +Cy^2$, or $y'^2=y^4 + Cy^2$. Hence
$$\pm\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{y^4+Cy^2}}=x + D$$